# Stoke' Theorem problem surface integral

Tags: calculus, stokes-theorem

Suppose $F = <-y ,x ,z>$ and $S$ is the part of the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 25$ below the plane $z=4$, oriented with the outward-pointing normal (so that the normal at $(5,0,0)$ is i). Compute the flux integral //curl F.dS using Stoke’s theorem?

Comment: I actually want to know how to find the answer by using surface integral not line integral...If someone could help me much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: the surface $S$ can be easily parametrized using spherical coordinates:
$$
x = 5\cos\theta\sin\phi,\qquad
y = 5\sin\theta\sin\phi,\qquad
z = 5\cos\phi,$$
$$\theta\in[0,2\pi],\qquad\phi\in[\arctan(3/4),\pi].$$

Comment: By using your hint above, ∬ curl F .n dS  = ∬ 2/5 z dS = -18pi. Why it got direct answer and not like this  - ∬ curl F .n dS = -(-18pi) (I put the negative because it clockwise direction and the correct answer should be -18pi). Sorry I haven't learned to edit and still newbie to this site so the expresssion look dull.

Comment: Ohh I know that integral does not need the minus sign because it does not depend on orientation right?

Comment: @SilverGray, the surface integral and the line integral depend *both* of the orientation. The orientation of $\partial S$ must be the orientation *induced* by $S$.

Comment: So the answer that I got, no need to put the minus sign because it already is induced?

Comment: @SilverGray, in this case the induced orientation is clockwise. See http://mathinsight.org/stokes_theorem_orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Denote the flux with $\Phi_F$. Notice that $div \bar F = 0$. Using Ostrogradsky theorem, we find:

If the plane is part of the surface, the entire surface is closed, so:

$$\Phi_F = \iint_S \bar F.\bar n dO = \iiint_V div \bar FdV = 0$$

Comment: Oh, I haven't learned that theorem yet. Thanks.

Comment: How come it doesn't prove the stoke's theorem by getting the same answer?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: By using line integral F.dr, I got the answer to be -18pi. Why it couldn't be the same by using flux integral? Opps I'm sorry I suppose to ask about flux integral to be precise.

Comment: How would you calculate the flux using a line integral?

Comment: By using the Stoke's theorem...

Comment: Stokes theorem says that $\iint_S curl(\bar F).\bar n dO = \int_C \bar F(\bar r).d\bar r $ where C is a closed curve (sorry I don't know how to write contour integrals in latex). How would you applu this here to calculate the flux?

Comment: A closed surface is required for Gauss-Ostrogradsk, The "lid" can be put on and off, but another (easier) surface integral is required.

Comment: Ah is the surface open? I thought the plane was part of the surface. If not, my answer is wrong.